# Facebook javascript sdk sharing gif animation dialogue box flicks

Tags: javascript, css, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am sharing Gif file / Animation file through fb js sdk. The dialogue box loads the animation file and the footer of the sharing dialogue box keep flicking as animation goes on.

I am using following code for this :

```
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'share',picture:'http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/3.gif',
    href: 'http://www.thisiscolossal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/3.gif'
}, function(response){});
```

Note : Image height is bigger than screen height then this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "picture" parameter for the Share Dialog, it only needs href and it will take the picture from the Open Graph tag (og:image): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#params